# Linq compare lists for equality and greater than

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to compare 2 lists using csharp and linq

typical scenarios i am trying to pull are

1. check if values in first list are equal to values in second list. if not what are differences. (Tried with intersect in linq and failed)
2. check if values in second list are greater than values in first list ie., first list = second list and second list have extra values than first list.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           List<Student> studentsSrcList = new List<Student>();

           Student s1 = new Student();
           s1.Name = "john1";
           s1.Address = "milwaukee1";
           s1.Phone = 1061;

           studentsSrcList.Add(s1);

           Student s2 = new Student();
           s2.Name = "john2";
           s2.Address = "milwaukee2";
           s2.Phone = 1062;

           studentsSrcList.Add(s2);

           List<Student> studentDestinationList = new List<Student>();

           Student s3 = new Student();
           s3.Name = "john1";
           s3.Address = "milwaukee1";
           s3.Phone = 1061;

           studentDestinationList.Add(s3);

           Student s4 = new Student();
           s4.Name = "john3";
           s4.Address = "milwaukee2";
           s4.Phone = 1064;

           studentDestinationList.Add(s4);

           Student s5 = new Student();
           s5.Name = "john5";
           s5.Address = "milwaukee5";
           s5.Phone = 1065;

           studentDestinationList.Add(s5);

           var diff = studentDestinationList.Intersect(studentsSrcList);
       } 
   }   

   class Student
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Address { get; set; }
       public int Phone { get; set; }
   }
   ```

I also tried var diff = studentsSrcList.SequenceEqual(studentsDestinationList);

Comment: Homework!!!!!!!

Comment: Esp. the second requirement, *values in second list are greater than values in first list*, is not well-defined. Also, you tell what you tried but not why it (apparently) didn't work out as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define when your objects of the class Student will be equal, or define a way to compare them.

You can do this by making class Student implement the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and/or have class Student override the [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Additionaly when you have a way of comparing your objects this will give you a count of objects that are in `studentDestinationList` but are not in `studentsSrcList`:

```
var diff = studentDestinationList.Count(x => !studentsSrcList.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing instances of reference types .Net by default compares the references, not the content. In your example s1 and s3 are different instances so they are not equal.

You can override Equals method in your Student class or make it implement IEquatable interface in order to compare the values in your class.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one this should work, (the second one is not clear)

```
List<Student> a = (from list1 in studentDestinationList
                    from list2 in studentsSrcList
                    where list1.Name == list2.Name && list1.Phone == list2.Phone && list1.Address == list2.Address
                    select list1).ToList();
```

Result at watch,
[image]

Hope helps,